# vimish-fold fold overlay highlight colour

Tags: code-folding

Is there a way to change `vimish-fold`'s fold highlight colour? I tried `customize-group` but didn't see an option to change it.

Comment: Try placing point over a highlighted part and typing `M-x describe-char`. It should give you info about faces, including one you want to customize.

Comment: It seems that it inherits it from `highlight`, and I can customize the highlight variable but that would apply to all modes. Can I hook it to `vimish-fold` mode only?

Comment: Have a look at the threads that describe how to use `face-remap-add-relative` which uses the variable `face-remapping-alist` to achieve buffer-local faces.  There is another method that works using a buffer-local variable that is set to the value of a face and the variable is called when applying faces rather than a face symbol, but the one mentioned in the previous sentence is the preferred method.

Comment: Done! Thank you both for your suggestions!